# BiarEnginer.jar/Command Line Import Documentation/Usage

Tags: business-objects, business-objects-sdk

Anyone know where the documentation is for the properites file?

I am trying the following exportQuery:

`select * form ci_infoobjects where si_kind like 'FavoritesFolder' and si_name like 't%'`

It is correctly grabbing the users but, is not biaring any of the folders/reports that said user has.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here is what I have found out.

- **documentation**: on the command line importe is in the bi_vip pdf provided by SAP (which I will provide a link to later).
- **usage**: My query isn't exactly correct but, removing the si_name portion should get you th right result.
- **issues**: It seems that the command line importer does not gracefully handler export errors. Any export error it receives the command line will kill itself.
- **work around**: I am pretty much duplicating the ImportWizard in java at this using API BIAROutput and IException.

I will hopefully post back my source code for the command line import tool in java.